# Bash completion - how to get rid of unneeded tab presses?

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion

I use

```
cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}" 

opts=`sqlite3 test.db "${QUERY[COMP_CWORD]}"`

SAVEIFS="$IFS"

IFS=$'\n'

COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -S"'" -P"'" -W "${opts}" $cur) )

IFS="$SAVEIFS"
```

to get possible variants from the database and complete them with <kbd>TAB</kbd>. As long as these variants could contain spaces, it is convinient to autoquote them using `'` as prefix and suffix, so when I press <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> and there is only one variant with `AB` prefix, then I get something like `'ABC DEF'`.

But the problem is that if there are many variants then after <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> I get `'AB`, then I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> once again and it is NOP, and only at the third <kbd>TAB</kbd> press I get possible completions.

Is there a way to reduce <kbd>TAB</kbd> pressings to one or at least two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try:

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
```

From `man bash`:

```
   show-all-if-ambiguous (Off)
          This alters the default behavior of the completion functions.  If set 
          to on, words which have more than one possible completion cause the 
          matches to be listed immediately instead of ringing the bell.
```

Comment: Perfect solution. This reduces TAB pressings to only one.

Comment: if not obvious: add `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` to ~/.inputrc to do this automatically.